# Cor em uma consulta SQL

Tags: php, sql

Gostaria de colocar uma com em uma consulta SQL por exemplo:

```
wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'first_name' or wp_usermeta.meta_key ='last_name'
```

Gostaria de colocar vermelho aqui `'last_name'` é possível?

Segue o código da consulta completo:

```
$sql = ("select DISTINCT ".TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE.".".DB_USERTABLE_USERID." userid, (select REPLACE(Group_concat(wp_usermeta.meta_value),',',' ') as full_name from wp_users left join wp_usermeta on wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id where (wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'first_name' or wp_usermeta.meta_key ='last_name') and wp_users.ID = userid) username, ".TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE.".user_nicename link, wp_usermeta.meta_value avatar, cometchat_status.lastactivity lastactivity, cometchat_status.status, cometchat_status.message, cometchat_status.isdevice from ".TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE." left join wp_usermeta on ".TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE.".".DB_USERTABLE_USERID." = wp_usermeta.user_id left join cometchat_status on ".TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE.".".DB_USERTABLE_USERID." = cometchat_status.userid ".$offlinecondition." and (wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'user_avatar' ) order by username asc");
```

Comment: Não entendi, quer colorir o seu código PHP é isso?

Comment: Se quer colocar cor não é na query que deve fazê-lo mas sim no PHP / HTML

Comment: Isso colocar no pHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na tag HTML que você estiver mostrando o resultado, basta colocar a propriedade color: red no style. Por exemplo, digamos que a tag que exiba o valor seja uma `<td>` de uma `<table>`:

```
<td style="color:red;">
```